# How can i wrap a selected text in custom comments in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to be able to write `some text`, select it and have a shortcut to automatically wrap it like this:

```c
/* ========= */
/* some text */
/* ========= */
```

I don't think I can use snippets, because the number of `=` is variable and depends on the length of the string inside. Is this possible?

Comment: use the **Hypersnips** extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy to do with a snippet:

```json
"wrapComment": {
  "prefix": "wc",
  "body": [
    "/* ${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/./=/g} */",
    "/* ${TM_SELECTED_TEXT} */",
    "/* ${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/./=/g} */"    
  ]
}
```

This part, with the `g` global flag, will replace each character in the selected text with a `=` - so it does the counting for you.

[image: make a wrapped comment]

Or as a keyboard shortcut (in your `keybindings.json`):

```json
{ 
  "key": "alt+/",            // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    "name": "wrapComment"   // using the name of the snippet from above
  }
}
```